# How to write "Everyone" in Chinese？

Tags: simplified-characters

Can anyone tell me how to write to "everyone" in Chinese. The symbol to write "everyone ". In a video they showed it to write people symbol 2 times. But when I am searching on Google it is not correct.

Comment: You said "people symbol 2 times", I think you meant " the character for 'people' twice" . 人 is a character or a word. We don't call characters  'symbols'.

Comment: Your question isn't so clear, and "everyone" doesn't mean “我们”, but "we" means 我们.

Comment: 人人 means "each and everyone/ everyone" as in " 人人有獎，永不落
空"

Comment: If you meant "to everyone (on the list)" then it is " 给(名单上的)每个人"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's easy, everyone means 所有人！all  of  us!

Answer (score 7):

我们＝we, us

everyone＝每人，人人，每个
"every" means 每 in Chinese.
"one" indicates people or thing.

So, the correct translation would be 每人 or 每个; and, in Chinese, 每人 is the same as 人人.

Comment: The difference between 每人and 人人 is  每人= "each person" ; 人人 = "everybody"

Answer (score 7):

The most common word for "everyone" is "大家".

However, since you mentioned "people symbol 2 times", you are probably looking for "人人", which is a special form for a few words. For example 人人 is everybody, 天天 is every day and so on. It is in fact a short form for 每个人 (each person).

Answer (score 2):

What have you found on google？It should be “每个人”、“大伙儿”和“大家”。

Also you can mean “大众”

You can use Google's Translation to translate it from English to Chinese：

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is actually writing the people symbol for 3 times

众 - means a crowd of people or a huge group of people 
人 - means people,basically
The word you are saying , writing the people symbol 2 times is 
从 - means from somewhere and etc

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not so straightforward, depends on context:

生活总是让**我们**遍体鳞伤,
The world breaks everyone (我们）,

人都到齐了。
Everyone (人都） is present.

1998年对所有人来说都是重要的一年：
1998 was an important year for everyone (所有人 都）:

大家都认为它有很大改进。 
Everyone (大家都） considered it a great improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I think everyone should be expressed as Chinese "各位"。

Answer (score 1):

Everyone  is  all ,so  in  Chinese  language it means  每个人，but everyone of who ，it up to context.

Answer (score -1):

It depends, especially for "人人" vs "每人".

When you are referring to an expectation or a convention, you use "人人". e.g. "人人有獎, 永不落空"

When you are referring to a rule or some kind of obligation, you use "每人". e.g. "每人一獎, 絕不欺場"